# Error while using osmosis

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

I was trying to filter openstreet map data using osmosis. I used the following

```
osmosis --read-xml city.osm --tf accept-ways highway=* --used-node --write-xml highways.osm
```

But while i run this command in osmosis with osm file "city.osm" it throws run time exception

`SEVERE: Thread for task 1-read-xml failed org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: Cannot represent 2169105896 as an integer. at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.util.LongAsInt.longToInt(LongAsInt.java:33)`

What could be the problem?

I updated osmosis to 0.43.1 version and it shows runtime exception

```
    SEVERE: Thread for task 1-read-xml failed
    org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: The entity timestamp attribute is missing.
at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.domain.common.UnparsedTimestampContainer<init>(UnparsedTimestampContainer.java:34)
```

Comment: Duplicated question: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/28118/error-while-using-osmosis

Comment: What happens if you use a different OSM file? The timestamp stuff with 0.43.1 looks like file contents issues to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using an old version of Osmosis.

Since Openstreetmap has hit the line of 2^64 node numbers, all software using the data had to change node number variables from integer to long integer.
If not, the software will return the error message you got.

Current versions of Osmosis have fixed this problem.

Comment: i updated osmosis to 0.43.1 version. please check the updated question.

Comment: For the timestamp issue: have you downloaded the data via Overpass api? They deliver timestamps only upon explicit request in the command using something like `<print mode="meta"/>`.

Comment: Thanks Andre the problem was with the data, it had no timestamps. I ran overpass query with meta printing mode and ran  osmosis ,it worked.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be an error with missing timestamp values in the OSM file. See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Talk:Osmosis#Producing_empty_timestamps . You need timestamps in the OSM XML, perhaps just fake them.

Comment: I've tried to fake them, but can't figure out how exactly to do it. Any tips?

Comment: Do you get your data from Overpass API? If so, see other answer. If not, set them to something like `1970-01-01T00:00`with a text editor (for testing) or programattically (using e.g. python minidom)

Comment: I tried `osmconvert --timestamp="properly formatted time"` but no dice. Ended up downloading `meta`, marginally larger files.